# Detecting the current context in regards to the audio/video play() command

Tags: javascript, audio, video, playback

So when we try to `myVideoElement.play()` for example, we get this error in the console:

*`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`*

Is it possible in JavaScript to detect or test what context we are in order to prevent calling the play() for example?  I do not want a warning or error message to show up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is the error in the console, you can just catch it.

```
async function yourFunction()
{
     try
     {
           await myVideoElement.play();
           // if the script reaches here, it succeeded
           console.log("success");
     }
     catch(error)
     {
           // if it failed it will come here, but will not put an error in the console,
           // so you can handle it however you want or just ignore it and nothing will happen
     }
}

yourFunction()
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

Comment: Yes, that intercepts the error message.  But there is also the warning message too: "Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted."